# How to modify default Web Deploy settings for a WebMatrix site?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, webmatrix, msdeploy, webdeploy

Is there a way to tweak Web Deploy settings when it's used via WebMatrix publishing dialog?

For example, I would like to force WebMatrix using the 'checksum' method of determining which files will be synced when a publish operation is performed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there a way to make WebMatrix pickup that setting from a .wpp.targets file?